# TypeInitializationException when using Nancy.Testing with NUnit test runner

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, nancy

I am writing a test using version 1.2 of `Nancy` and `Nancy.Testing` via `NuGet`. My test is written with `NUnit` 2.6.4 and looks like this:

```
[Test]
public async Task ShouldReturnSuccessfullyAuthenticatedUser()
{
    // arrange
    var request = CreateRequest();
    var userDocument = CreateUserDocumentFrom(request);
    await userRepository.AddAsync(userDocument);

    // act
    var response = browser.Post(Paths.Login, with => with.JsonBody(request));

    // assert
    response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

I have this exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'Nancy.Bootstrapper.AppDomainAssemblyTypeScanner' threw an exception.
  ----> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException : Could not find a part of the path 'E:\myProject\bin\Debug\bin\Debug'.
```

And I think there's something wrong when using `Nancy.Testing` with `NUnit`, because the equivalent test in `xUnit` runs just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looked like `NUnit` was tryging to automatically add `bin\Debug` to the bin path. The way I solved it is to specify explicitly what kind of bin path to use. Here is the `.nunit` project file:

```
<NUnitProject>
  <Settings activeconfig="Debug" />
  <Config name="Debug" binpathtype="Manual">
    <assembly path="bin/Debug/MyUnitTests1.dll" />
    <assembly path="bin/Debug/MyUnitTests2.dll" />
  </Config>
  <Config name="Release" binpathtype="Manual">
    <assembly path="bin/Release/MyUnitTests1.dll" />
    <assembly path="bin/Release/MyUnitTests2.dll" />
  </Config>
</NUnitProject>
```

The XML attribute `NUnitProject\Config\binpathtype` had previously a value of `Auto`. When I changed it to `Manual` as above the exception was gone and my tests ran successfully.

Comment: Where do i find this file? can't find any file ending with .nunit in my visual studio solution. Getting the same error when trying to run nunit-console.exe from Jenkins.

Comment: This is a file you define yourself and pass it to the nunit-console.exe as a parameter

Comment: I see Thanks @ceko , solved the issue by pointing to the test .dlls instead of the project files.